# How do I assign series or sequences to dask dataframe column?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

My **dask dataframe** is the follwing:

```
In [65]: df.head()
Out[65]:
   id_orig  id_cliente  id_cartao  inicio_processo  fim_processo  score  \
0      1.0         1.0        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
1      1.0         1.0        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
2      1.0         1.0        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
3      1.0         1.0        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
4      1.0         1.0        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0

   automatico  canal  aceito  motivo_recusa  variante
0         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
1         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
2         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
3         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
4         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
```

Assigning an integer works:

```
In [92]: df = df.assign(id_cliente=999)

In [93]: df.head()
Out[93]:
   id_orig  id_cliente  id_cartao  inicio_processo  fim_processo  score  \
0      1.0         999        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
1      1.0         999        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
2      1.0         999        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
3      1.0         999        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0
4      1.0         999        1.0              1.0           1.0    1.0

   automatico  canal  aceito  motivo_recusa  variante
0         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
1         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
2         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
3         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
4         1.0    1.0     1.0            1.0       1.0
```

However no other method for assigning Series or any other iterable in existing columns works.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataFrame.assign accepts any scalar or any `dd.Series`

```
df = df.assign(a=1)  # accepts scalars
df = df.assign(z=df.x + df.y)  # accepts dd.Series objects
```

If you are trying to assign a NumPy array or Python list then it might be your data is small enough to fit in RAM, and so Pandas might be a better fit than Dask.dataframe.

You can also use plain setitem syntax

```
df['a'] = 1
df['z'] = df.x + df.y
```